# upload file by streamming :shows error log "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)"

Tags: ios, upload, streaming

I'm trying to upload big file by streaming, recently I got this error log:

```
Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x103c0610 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=/adv,/cgi-bin/file_upload-cgic, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey/adv,/cgi-bin/file_upload-cgic}<br>
```

this is where I set bodystream:

```
-(void)finishedRequestBody{ // set bodyinput stream
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",[self getBoundaryStr]]];
    [bodyFileOutputStream close];
    bodyFileOutputStream = nil;
    //calculate content length
    NSError *fileReadError = nil;
    NSDictionary *fileAttrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:pathToBodyFile error:&fileReadError];
    NSAssert1((fileAttrs != nil),@"Couldn't read post body file",fileReadError);
    NSNumber *contentLength = [fileAttrs objectForKey:NSFileSize];

   NSInputStream *bodyStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:pathToBodyFile];
    [request setHTTPBodyStream:bodyStream];
    [bodyStream release];

    if (staticUpConneciton == nil) {          
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];    
        staticUpConneciton = [[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self] retain];                   
    }else{
        staticUpConneciton = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]retain];
    }  
}
```

this is how I write the steam:

```
    -(void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{
        uint8_t buf[1024*100];
        NSUInteger len = 0;
        switch (eventCode) {
            case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
                NSLog(@"media file opened");
                break;
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
              //  NSLog(@"should never happened for output stream");
                len = [self.uploadFileInputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
                if (len) {
                    [self.bodyFileOutputStream write:buf maxLength:len];
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"buf finished wrote %@",self.pathToBodyFile);
                    [self handleStreamCompletion];
                }
                break;
            case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
                NSLog(@"stream error");
                break;
            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
                NSLog(@"should never for output stream");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

close stream

```
-(void)finishMediaInputStream{
    [self.uploadFileInputStream close];
    [self.uploadFileInputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.uploadFileInputStream = nil;
}

-(void)handleStreamCompletion{
    [self finishMediaInputStream];
    // finish requestbody
    [self finishedRequestBody];
}
```

and I found that error when I implement this method needNewBodyStream: see the following code:

```
-(NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)request{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    NSInputStream *fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:pathToBodyFile];
    if (fileStream == nil) {
        NSLog(@"NSURLConnection was asked to retransmit a new body stream for a request. returning nil!");
    }
    return fileStream;
}
```

this is where I set the headers and mediaInputStream

```
-(void)setPostHeaders{
    pathToBodyFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(),bodyFileName];
    bodyFileOutputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:pathToBodyFile append:YES];
    [bodyFileOutputStream open];

    //set bodysteam
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", [self getBoundaryStr]]];
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"target_path"]];
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",UploaderController.getDestination,APP_UPLOADER,[Functions getDateString]]]];
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", [self getBoundaryStr]]];
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_path\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName]];
    [self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"]];

    NSString *tempFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"uploadFile"]; 

    NSError *fileReadError = nil;
    NSDictionary *fileAttrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:tempFile error:&fileReadError];
    NSAssert1((fileAttrs != nil),@"Couldn't read post body file",fileReadError);
    NSNumber *contentLength = [fileAttrs objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    [request setValue:[contentLength stringValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    
    NSInputStream *mediaInputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:tempFile];
    self.uploadFileInputStream = mediaInputStream;    
    [self.uploadFileInputStream setDelegate:self];
    [self.uploadFileInputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.uploadFileInputStream open];    
}
```

this is how I copy data from camera roll

```
-(void)copyFileFromCamaroll:(ALAssetRepresentation *)rep{
    //copy the file from the camarall to tmp folder (automatically cleaned out every 3 days)
    NSUInteger chunkSize = 100 * 1024;
    NSString *tempFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"uploadFile"];
    NSLog(@"tmpfile %@",tempFile);
    uint8_t *chunkBuffer = malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    NSUInteger length = [rep size];

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: tempFile] retain];
    if(fileHandle == nil) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tempFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
        fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:tempFile] retain];
    }

    NSUInteger offset = 0;
    do {
        NSUInteger bytesCopied = [rep getBytes:chunkBuffer fromOffset:offset length:chunkSize error:nil];
        offset += bytesCopied;
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:chunkBuffer length:bytesCopied];
        [fileHandle writeData:data];
        [data release];
    } while (offset < length);
    [fileHandle closeFile];
    [fileHandle release];
    free(chunkBuffer);
    chunkBuffer = NULL;          
    NSError *error;
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempFile options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
    if (!fileData) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error description]);
        NSLog(@"%@", tempFile);
        //do what you need with the error
    }            
}
```

anybody, any ideas? Did I miss something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077284/what-is-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-303)

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

In order to mention this upfront:

In iOS 7, there is probably an easy solution to upload a large *file*. Please refer to `NSURLSession`, `NSURLSessionTask`, especially:

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                                         fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL 
                                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

---

Otherwise,

your code has a number of issues:

- The multipart message is not constructed properly (including the content length).
- You use `sendSynchronousRequest` and mixing them with delegate methods. Delete the line:

  ```
  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];)
  ```
- Assuming you want to upload an asset by creating a temporary file, you can accomplish this (creating a temp file from an asset) much more easily. In fact, you don't need the stream delegate method. An alternative approach avoiding the temp file requires a "bound pair of streams" - and then you need the stream delegate. The latter is more complex, though.

Given your requirements, ***I would strongly recommend to use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode implementing the delegates.***

Your problem still has enough stuff to be split into three or more questions, thus I will restrict to answer only one issue:

When uploading a *file* to a server there are a few established approaches how this can be accomplished with HTTP. The suggested way (but not the only way) is to use a `POST` request with a `multipart/form-data` media type with a special *Disposition*.

Lets take a look at your code at the part that is related to *uploading* the file:

The code you provided seems to have an issue in statement

```
[self appendBodyString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",[self getBoundaryStr]]];
```

at the beginning of method `finishedRequestBody`. This looks like the "closing delimiter" of a "multi-part body" which must appear after the last part - but not earlier. So, here is a bug.

Now, let's figure out how to construct a correct `multipart/form-data` message:

#### Constructing a multipart message for file upload

We assume you *already* have the file which you want to upload at path *pathToBodyFile* represented as a `NSInputStream`. This is done correctly in statement:

```
NSInputStream *bodyStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:pathToBodyFile];
```

The rules to upload a file via a multipart/form-data message are defined in [RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) "**Form-based File Upload in HTML**" and a whole bunch of related and dependent RFCs which specify the protocol *in great detail* (you don't need to read it now, but possibly later).

There was a question recently on SO, where I made an attempt to clarify a multipart media type: [NSURLRequest Upload Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879469/nsurlrequest-upload-multiple-files/18924214#18924214). I would recommend to take a look there, too.

A file upload according RFC 1867 is basically a multipart/form-data message, except that it *can* use a *specialized* Disposition where you can specify the original file name in a disposition parameter. The related RFCs are [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) "Returning Values from Forms: multipart/form-data", and a few dozens more, possibly especially relevant [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), [RFC 6657](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6657), [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231) ).

**Note:** if you have any *specific* question about any details, it is always recommended to read the related RFCs. (finding the newest and actual ones is a challenge though.)

A `multipart/form-data` message contains a series of *parts*. A form-data part consists of some "parameter name" or "label" (represented via a disposition header), other optional headers, and a body.

Each *part* MUST have a *content-disposition* header (representing the "parameter name" or "label") whose "value" equals "form-data" and which has a *name attribute* which specifies a *field name* (usually but not exclusively referring to a field in a "HTTP form"). For example:

```
content-disposition: form-data; name="fieldname"
```

Each part may have an optional `Content-Type` header. If no one is specified, `text/plain` is assumed.

After the headers (if any) the *body* follows.

So, a part may be viewed as a "parameter/value" pair (plus some optional headers).

If the body is a file content, you can specify the original file name in the content-disposition with a *filename* parameter, e.g.:

```
content-disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
```

Additionally, you SHOULD set the `Content-Type` header for this part accordingly, matching the actual file type, e.g.:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

A `multipart/form-data` message body consists of *one* or more parts. The parts are separated with a *boundary*.

(How you set the boundaries, is described in more detail in the given link here on SO [NSURLRequest Upload Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879469/nsurlrequest-upload-multiple-files/18924214#18924214) and in the related RFCs.)

---

#### Example:

Upload a file "image.jpg" whose MIME type is "image/jpeg"

Create a HTTP message with method `POST` and set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data` specifying a *boundary*:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
```

The "multipart body" of a "multipart/form-data" message consisting of *one* part looks as follows (note: CRLF are *explicitly* visible):

```
\r\n--AaB03x\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
\r\n<file-content>--AaB03x--
```

Now, you need to "translate" this "outline" into Objective-C with the use of `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest`, which seems to be straight forward at the first glance. However, there arise a couple of subtle problems:

First:

A *multipart* message body consists of *one* or more parts. As you can see, a part itself contains the boundary and headers plus the body. Constructing a part body now becomes complex since a part's body is a *stream* (your file input stream). The task is now to "merge" a `NSData` object (boundary and headers) and the file *input stream* resulting in (some abstract) *new input source*. This new *input source* together with other parts (if any) are now required to form again a *new input source* which is finally a `NSInputStream` representing the whole *multipart body* of the `multipart/form-data` request. This *eventual* input stream must be set as the `HTTPBodyStream` property of the `NSMutableURLRequest`.

I admit, this is a *challenge* requiring a number of helper classes, and its own Unit Tests!

A simplification using a memory mapped file as representation for the *large* asset file is probably futile, since you need to form (aka merge) a *complete* multipart body (one or more parts). This will end up as a `NSData` object containing headers and file content, ultimately allocated on the heap. This is likely to fail for very large assets (>300MByte).

A solution is to use a *bound pair of streams* (an Input Stream and an OutputStream connected via a fixed size buffer), where the one end, the Output Stream, is used to *write* all parts (headers and file content via input stream), and the other end, the Input Stream, is used to "bind" to the `HTTPBodyStream` property.

A solution for this single problem is worth a new SO question. (There are Samples from Apple which demonstrate this technique).

There are existing solutions which makes it easy to setup a multipart/form-data request provided by third party libs. However, even well known third party libraries do struggle to get this right.

Second:

#### A Warning:

Like any "language", the HTTP protocol is very picky about the correct syntax, that is - occurrences of separator elements, character encoding, escaping and quoting, etc. For example, if you miss a CRLF or if you miss to apply the *proper* encoding for a certain string (e.g. a file name) or if you not apply quoting where necessary within some element of the protocol (e.g. boundary or a filename), your server may not understand the message, or misinterpret it.

There is a huge bunch of RFCs that try to unambiguously specify the nitty gritty details. But careful, finding the RFC which actually specifies the current problem will require some effort. And RFCs get updated and obsoleted once in a while ending in a different "current" RFC. So, keep this in mind when writing code: there might be edge cases where your code is not written according the current RFC and you get unexpected behavior.

So, you might now take the challenge - and this is really advanced stuff - and try to implement a "***multipart/form-data body as NSInputStream***" correctly, or you try a third party solution, which *may* work under certain conditions, or sometimes not.

---

#### Tips and Hints for a File Upload with `NSURLRequest`

- For larger files use a `NSInputStream` representation for the file,
  instead of a `NSData` representation. (You may experiment with mapped
  file and `NSData` though, too).
- When setting a `NSInputStream` as request body, don't open the input
  stream.
- When setting a `NSInputStream` as request body you must override the
  `connection:needNewBodyStream:` delegate method and provide a new
  stream object again. (You did this correctly, though I don't
  understand the purpose of the delay.)
- When providing an *input stream* as request body *without* setting a
  `Content-Length` header explicitly, `NSURLConnection` will use
  "[chunked transfer
  encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)".
  Usually, this isn't a problem for the server - but in cases where it
  is, you might set the `Content-Length` explicitly (if you can
  determine the length) and `NSURLConnection` will not use "chunked
  transfer encoding" to transmit the request body anymore.
- When setting the "Content-Length" header, be sure you set the
  *correct* length.
- When using a `NSData` object as request body, you don't need to set a
  `Content-Length` header, `NSURLConnection` will set this
  automatically, unless specified explicitly.
- File names in the *Disposition header* possibly require quoting and encoding (see [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231)).

Comment: I really appreciated your quick response and your advice, thank your so much. BTW, you mentioned that I have 3 or more problems  to discuss, can you tell me what are those problems? so that I can google those later. and actually I can only upload file >80MB, over 80MB , app crashed! I think this is one of my another problems you mentioned

Comment: Hi, I just come up some quesions 
1. you said using iOS 7 "NSURLSession, NSURLSessionTask" is easier, did you mean that if I use that(NSURLSession, NSURLSessionTask), there is no need to handle stream issue or what? 
2. if unfortunately I still can't fix those problems, can you suggest me which third party you recommend to use? like AFNetworking, or others?

Comment: you mentioned "a bound pair of streams" again. I am not very  clear about this yet. Do this outputstream and inputstream work at the same time? I mean when write outputstream (not finish)also read inputstream and set the httpbodystream at the same time? Because what I implement is wait to finish whole stream job and then setHTTPBodyStream for upload.

Comment: update: after I thought about pair stream(for asset), I implement the method copyFileFromCameraroll (not use bound pair streams), so that asset(mediaInputStream) file is copy to temp dir

Comment: I think, you need first decide about the strategy to solve your problem: 1) use iOS 7 only methods (as mentioned). If this works for you, this is the easiest solution. 2) Use a third party library, keeping in mind that there *may* issues anyway (or not). This is basically easy as well. 3) Implement your own solution. This is a really pretty hard and an advanced challenge when you want it to be _correct_ considering your requirements: large files (>80 MByte), cancelable request, restartable request, "rewindable" request body.

Comment: A "bounded pair of stream", is an Input Stream and an Output Stream pair which is connected via a fixed size buffer. You create these streams with CF function `CFStreamCreateBoundPair`. You use this for example when you have many _fragments_ of "input data" which comprise the complete request body. You write each fragment into the Output Stream, and on the other end, the input stream is read by  `NSURLConnection` through the request's `HTTPBodyStream` property. (The Input Stream is assigned the request body's property `HTTPBodyStream`.)

Comment: Basically, using "Streams" reduces the memory foot-print, since only a fixed and a small number of bytes (buffer size) is required to be allocated to transfer a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Currently,I found out what cause this error log is wrong content-length.
Originally, I set the content-length is only due to the size of upload file(not including post data).
this is the wrong code in setPostHeaders method:

```
NSString *tempFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"uploadFile"]; 
NSError *fileReadError = nil;
NSDictionary *fileAttrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:tempFile error:&fileReadError];
NSAssert1((fileAttrs != nil),@"Couldn't read post body file",fileReadError);
NSNumber *contentLength = [fileAttrs objectForKey:NSFileSize];
[request setValue:[contentLength stringValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

and I set the size of Content-Length  by using pathToBodyFile (this file includes post data)

```
NSDictionary *fileAttrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:pathToBodyFile error:&fileReadError];
NSAssert1((fileAttrs != nil),@"Couldn't read post body file",fileReadError);
NSNumber *contentLength = [fileAttrs objectForKey:NSFileSize];
//NSLog(@"2 body length %@",[contentLength stringValue]);
[request setValue:[contentLength stringValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]
```

and finally, the error log was gone. I don't know why this work. I had thought that the content length is set to the upload file, but actually, the content length is set to the size of file which include post data and upload file