Swift multipart/form-data request
I've been trying to get a request to work to the following endpoint for several days and have had absolutely no luck. However, I was able to hit this endpoint via postman and even trimmed down the request to only include the json and not the file keys.
My request fails with the following error: parse: incomplete multipart stream.
Furthermore, I inspected the raw request postman sent and tried to replicate that as close as possible in Swift (their code snippet is incorrect) and haven't been able to receive a 200 status code.
Endpoint
curl https://api.hume.ai/v0/batch/jobs \
 --request POST \
 --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
 --header "X-Hume-Api-Key: <YOUR API KEY>" \
 --form json='{
    "models": {
        "language": {}
    }
 }' \
 --form file={some file uri}

My Implementation
Note: I'm not sending a value for file key as it's not required and I want to get a 200 status code prior to adding that complexity. I confirmed file is not required via postman.
        // Create value for 'json' key
        var jsonBody: Data
        do {
            
            let json: [String: Any] = [
                "models": [
                    "language": [String: Any]()
                ]
            ]
            
            jsonBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        } catch {
            print("Error serializing JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        // Create the request object and boundary
        let boundary = "--------------------------\(UUID().uuidString)"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(
            string: "https://api.hume.ai/v0/batch/jobs"
        )!)
        
        // Init request headers
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue(HUME_API_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Hume-Api-Key")
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // Build request body
        var body = Data()
        body += Data("\(boundary)\r\n".utf8)
        body += Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n".utf8)
        body += Data("Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n".utf8)
        
        body += jsonBody
        body += Data("\r\n".utf8)
        
        body += Data("\(boundary)--\r\n".utf8)

        // Set body to request object
        request.httpBody = body

When printing out my request to the console I get the following which appears correct
X-Hume-Api-Key: MY_API_KEY
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------34C72EAC-C0E0-45ED-83D2-3D1D6E79BCFE
--------------------------34C72EAC-C0E0-45ED-83D2-3D1D6E79BCFE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json

{"models":{"language":{}}}
--------------------------34C72EAC-C0E0-45ED-83D2-3D1D6E79BCFE--


Is there something that I'm missing or not formatting correctly? I've spent a fair amount of time reading over this protocol to ensure I'm following the correct request guidelines as well as trying to match postman 1:1. Thanks all!
Minimal Code to Reproduce Issue
        // Create value for 'json' key
        var jsonBody: Data
        do {
            let json: [String: Any] = [
                "models": [
                    "language": [String: Any]()
                ]
            ]
            
            jsonBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        } catch {
            print("Error serializing JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        // Create the request object and boundary
        let boundary = "--------------------------\(UUID().uuidString)"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(
            string: "https://api.hume.ai/v0/batch/jobs"
        )!)
        
        // Init request headers
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue(HUME_API_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Hume-Api-Key")
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // Build request body
        var body = Data()
        body += Data("\(boundary)\r\n".utf8)
        body += Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n".utf8)
        body += Data("Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n".utf8)
        
        body += jsonBody
        body += Data("\r\n".utf8)
        
        body += Data("\(boundary)--\r\n".utf8)

        // Set body to request object
        request.httpBody = body
        
        // Display request
        for header in request.allHTTPHeaderFields! {
            print("\(header.key): \(header.value)")
        }
        print(String(data: request.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)!)

        // Send request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let response = response {
                print("response: \(response)")
            } else {
                return
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                // Print response status code (i.e 400)
                print("status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            } else {
                print("failed to cast to HTTPURLResponse")
                return
            }

            if let data = data, let responseBody = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                // Print response
                print("response body: \(responseBody)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()


Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code . Show how you send the request and how you collect/print the results.

@workingdogsupportUkraine - I just updated the description to include a full code snippet that reproduces the issue (assuming you provide an API key for Hume: https://www.hume.ai/)

Can't see anything wrong. As I understand postman can generate Swift code for you.
Maybe this would give you some more info about the problem.

I tried using the code generated from postman and it doesn't compile haha. I also tried fixing it but didn't have any luck getting it to work unfortunately.

The first line in the body needs to be "--\(boundary)\r\n". The last line (after appending a CRLF to the actual payload) needs to be "--\(boundary)--". Note: don't confuse the two dashes before a boundary with the boundary itself. The two dashes are an explicit prefix. Characters after the closing boundary will be ignored by the server.

That is what the postman generated code has:
body += Data("--\(boundary)\r\n".utf8) and body += Data("--\(boundary)--\r\n".utf8) ,
but according to the OP it still does not work.

For a more elaborate answer, you may look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18924214/465677

@workingdogsupportUkraine The current OP code is not correct. For example, when you look very closely, the boundary is defined in the "content-type" header. Then, the first line of the body should be "--\(boundary)\r\n".  Actually it is "(boundary)\r\n". Your code by Postman, though is correct. :)

yes I agree, the code shown is not correct. My point is that the OP says they tried the Postman generated code without success. That code is now shown, so maybe it was not copied properly or there is something else at play. Since I don't have an api key I cannot test anything.

Postman code doesn't compile? Could you still share it? Also, is the file parameter mandatory?

correction to my previous comment, I meant to say That code is not shown,... instead of That code is now shown,.... Note that the Postman generated code compiles for me.

The code shown above is not from postman as I couldn't get that code to compile. I also tried appending -- to the initial body as proposed but then I got an new error saying my json key was not parsable for reasons that I don't understand..

The raw postman request (that works via postman) has this form
POST /v0/batch/jobs HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------565905063365356582515311
X-Hume-Api-Key: API_KEY
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.39.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: TOKEN
Host: api.hume.ai
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 240
 
----------------------------565905063365356582515311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json
{
"models": {
"language": {}
}
}
----------------------------565905063365356582515311--


@EsotericLanguage did you ever get this sorted? I also struggled for a long time trying to get form/multipart to work. I eventually just used AlamoFire, which handles them nicely, but I dislike dependencies and would rather figure out how to roll my own. I've been studying the AF source for clues.
